# use substr while join in laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel-9

```
   $calendar = Calendar::selectRaw('*,substr(bio_id,2,1) as bio')
        ->where('start_date',$request->hasil)
        ->join('employees','employees.id', '=', 'calendars.bio_id')
        ->get();
```

I have a problem to subtract string in column ('bio_id') in table calendars while joining table employees into table calendars

how to fix that's thanks

Comment: Use raw expression as joining condition.